# In Python, how do I convert a list of ints and strings to Unicode?

Tags: python, unicode

```
x = ['Some strings.', 1, 2, 3, 'More strings!', 'Fanc\xc3\xbf string!']
y = [i.decode('UTF-8') for i in x]
```

What's the best way to convert the strings in x to Unicode?  Doing a list compression causes an attribute error (`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'`) because int's don't have a decode method.

I could use a for loop with a try?  Or I could do some explicit type checking in the list compression, but is type checking in a dynamic language like Python the right approach?

UPDATE:

I would prefer that the int's remain int's. Although this is not a strict requirement.  My ideal output would be `[u'Some strings.', 1, 2, 3, u'More strings!', u'Fancÿ string!']`.

Comment: What is your desired output? `[u'Some strings', 1, 2, 3, u'More strings!']`, `[u'Some strings', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'More strings!']`, `[u'Some strings', u'More strings!']` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to keep the integers as they are in the list while just changing the strings to unicode, you can do

```
x = ['Some strings.', 1, 2, 3, 'More strings!']
y = [i.decode('UTF-8') if isinstance(i, basestring) else i for i in x]
```

which gets you

```
[u'Some strings.', 1, 2, 3, u'More strings!']
```

Comment: You could also do this using a loop and a try/catch block, but I think this is tidier.

Comment: The try/catch block would work on objects which have a decode method, but are not instances of basestring.  Which preserves a feature of dynamic languages: you don't have to do a lot of type checking and fancy inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, it's a compromise between brevity and programming using the dynamic philosophy. I'm of the mind that you should generally avoid using try/catch for flow control if you can help it, but both solutions could be appropriate depending on your mindset/situation.

Comment: How can this be made safe for both Python 2/3?

Comment: There are a few suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301138/how-to-check-if-variable-is-string-with-python-2-and-3-compatibility

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [unicode](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode) function:

```
>>> x = ['Some strings.', 1, 2, 3, 'More strings!']
>>> y = [unicode(i) for i in x]
>>> y
[u'Some strings.', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'More strings!']
```

**UPDATE**: since you specified that you want the integers to remain as-is, I would use this:

```
>>> y = [unicode(i) if isinstance(i, basestring) else i for i in x]
>>> y
[u'Some strings.', 1, 2, 3, u'More strings!']
```

Note: as @Boldewyn points out, if you want UTF-8, you should pass the `encoding` parameter to the unicode function:

```
unicode(i, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: This only works for ASCII (the `decode()` is there for a purpose). And it converts the numbers to type `unicode`.

Comment: *Only* if you tell the Python interpreter via `-*- coding -*-` pragmas. And Unicode != UTF-8, sorry.

Comment: @Boldewyn you can pass the ``encoding`` parameter to the ``unicode`` function and it does the exact same thing as ``.decode``

Comment: Yes, that's true. I forgot about this. But you should incorporate it in the answer.

Comment: @jterrace: Very right, it's the same as `.decode()`, even to the extent that it won't work for integers any more.