# Convert variable types into unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, int

I'm looking for a way to convert a variable (which could be an ASCII string, unicode string WITH extra characters like é or £, or a floats or integer) into a unicode string.

`variable.encode('utf-8')` where `variable` is an integer results in `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'`

`str(variable).encode('utf-8')` where `variable` is the string `'£'` results in `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Is there an easy way to do what I'm looking for in Python 2.7? Or do I have to check the type of variable and process it differently?

Answer (score 4):

Encoding would never result in a `unicode` object. You *decode* from bytes to `unicode`.

As such, you'd convert to `str` (a byte string) then to `unicode` by decoding:

```
str(obj).decode('utf8')
```

This will still fail for objects that are *already* `unicode` values, so you may want to use `try..except` to catch that case:

```
try:
    obj = str(obj).decode('utf8')
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    # already unicode
    pass
```

If you try to encode a byte-string, Python 2 implicitly first decodes to `unicode` for you, which is why you got your `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: converting to str(obj) will create the problem with the unicode chars so you can not just use str('some unicode char')

Comment: @OmidS.: which is why there is a `try...except` case to **catch exactly that issue**. In Python 2, for *bytestrings*, `str('some bytes that encode non-ASCII codepoints')` is just fine. For a `unicode` object, `str(u'unicode string with non-ASCII codepoints')` will in deed fail, but the exception handler is there for exactly that case.

Answer (score -1):

this is an old post but I had the exact same problem :/ I ended up using the `unicode` function. this is a builtin function you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#unicode)

so the only change is instead of `str(theThing)` you can use `unicode(theThing)` , as said in documentation it does behave like `str` except it converts to a unicode string not an ascii one.

just as a word of caution if you are using some kind of file writing or some other stuff you might run into problems there as well or at least I did :D and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571151/in-python-how-do-i-convert-a-list-of-ints-and-strings-to-unicode?answertab=active#tab-top) fixed mine

Comment: This does the wrong thing for the exact example the OP has: A bytestring with non-ASCII bytes, like `’£’`.

Comment: If you *already* have a Unicode string, you’d have to test for that; since that’s the only exception it’s easier to use `str(...).decode(...)` for everything else.

Comment: well I'm not much of python guy but the documentation is pretty clear if you take a look ( the "here" link, first  paragraph ), at least in python 2.7 that exact function is there to serve that purpose.

Comment: The problem arises when you pass in something that contains non-ASCII bytes, which will fail decoding.